# tidyr::expand() for a single column across groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

`tidyr::expand()` returns all possible combinations of values from multiple columns. I'm looking for a slightly different behavior, where all the values are in a single column and the combinations are to be taken across groups.

For example, let the data be defined as follows:

```
library( tidyverse )
X <- bind_rows( data_frame(Group = "Group1", Value = LETTERS[1:3]),
                data_frame(Group = "Group2", Value = letters[4:5]) )
```

We want all combinations of values from `Group1` with values from `Group2`. My current clunky solution is to separate the values across multiple columns

```
Y <- X %>% group_by(Group) %>% do(vals = .$Value) %>% spread(Group, vals)
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   Group1    Group2   
#   <list>    <list>   
# 1 <chr [3]> <chr [2]>
```

followed by a double `unnest` operation

```
Y %>% unnest( .preserve = Group2 ) %>% unnest
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Group1 Group2
#   <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 A      d     
# 2 A      e     
# 3 B      d     
# 4 B      e     
# 5 C      d     
# 6 C      e
```

This is the desired output, but as you can imagine, this solution doesn't generalize well: as the number of groups increases, so does the number of `unnest` operations that we have to perform.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: `expand.grid(split(X$Value, X$Group))`

Comment: How would you expect a third case to be handled?

Comment: Thanks, @Henrik. So simple! I ended up slapping a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` on top of that `expand.grid()` call. If you make your comment into an actual answer, I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because OP seems happy to use `base`, I upgrade my comment to an answer:

```
expand.grid(split(X$Value, X$Group))
#   Group1 Group2
# 1      A      d
# 2      B      d
# 3      C      d
# 4      A      e
# 5      B      e
# 6      C      e
```

As noted by OP, `expand.grid` converts character vectors to factors. To prevent that, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

The `tidyverse` equivalent is `purrr::cross_df`, which doesn't coerce to factor:

```
cross_df(split(X$Value, X$Group))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Group1 Group2
# <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 A      d     
# 2 B      d     
# 3 C      d     
# 4 A      e     
# 5 B      e     
# 6 C      e
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option. It will work on the cases with more than two groups although `complete_` is deprecated.

```
library( tidyverse )
X2 <- X %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(Group, Value) %>%
  select(-ID) %>%
  complete_(names(.)) %>%
  na.omit()
X2
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Group1 Group2
#   <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 A      d     
# 2 A      e     
# 3 B      d     
# 4 B      e     
# 5 C      d     
# 6 C      e
```

**Update**

`!!!syms(names(.))` works well with the regular `complete` function, thus is better than using `complete_` as my original solution.

```
library( tidyverse )
X2 <- X %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(Group, Value) %>%
  select(-ID) %>%
  complete(!!!syms(names(.))) %>%
  na.omit()
X2
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Group1 Group2
#   <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 A      d     
# 2 A      e     
# 3 B      d     
# 4 B      e     
# 5 C      d     
# 6 C      e
```

Comment: Thanks, www. I ended up going with Henrick's solution, but `mutate(ID = 1:n())` is the key ingredient I was missing when trying to separate groups of varying lengths into individual columns! I'll have to remember the `!!!syms(...)` trick too.

Comment: I like Henrick’s method, too. Thanks for this interesting question.

Comment: @www, I think you need to add the ```library(rlang)``` call to your second example to use the ```syms()``` function?  That will help future folks trying to run it (took me a while to figure out which library I was missing).  Also, what does the ```!!!``` do in front of ```syms()```?

Comment: @JRT If I load `tidyverse` only, the code still works on my machine. It looks like `syms` is also a function from the `dplyr` package. I cannot explain `!!!` very well, so please see this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html to learn more.

Comment: Interesting. I had ```tidyverse``` loaded first and it didn't work until I loaded ```rlang```.  Will take a look and see what I'm missing. Thanks for the pointer on ```!!!```.

Answer (score 1):

I often use `tidyr::crossing()` to join all values from `group2` to `group`.

```
data_frame(group = c(LETTERS[1:3])) %>% 
  crossing(group2 = letters[4:5])
```

I might do something like this:

```
data %>% 
  distinct(group) %>% 
  crossing(group2)
```

A more specific example:

```
dates <- lubridate::make_date(2000:2018)

data_frame(group = letters[1:5]) %>% 
  crossing(dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

This still works with `expand` after `spread`.

```
X %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  spread(Group, Value) %>%
  expand(Group1, Group2) %>%
  na.omit()
```